# what interview questions should you ask of a user experience (ux) developer/designer

Tags: usability, user-experience

We are hiring a UX consultant, had a broadstrokes session with the company, liked their work, think the candidates are ok and now want a more concentrated interview with the specific UX consultant that will be embedded into the scrum team.

What questions should be asking that could weed out any dead weight candidates.

Thanks.

Comment: The answers so far seem to think you're hiring a UI designer, perhaps you should clarify more what it is you expect them to do.

Comment: The distance between UI and UX is not that great, but I agree clarification is required. Also wiki I'm thinking.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience_design

We're interviewing mostly consultants that do the "design" part of the above mentioned wiki and also talking to one information architect.  Thanks for the replies so far, they've been very helpful.

Comment: Had to vote down...not a programming question...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Ask Tog has a good Quiz](http://www.asktog.com/columns/022DesignedToGiveFitts.html). I'd also ask stuff on the [Gestalt principles](http://tinyurl.com/y6ao7k), but that's probably because I have a masters degree in HCI (as in that might be a bit academic). That said Gestalt principles are very important especially for things like Form design.

I guess also you could ask them what their favourite book on UX design are, if they can't list any that would be very odd to me.

Comment: For those viewing this question in the 2010's, take Tog's quiz with a grain of salt.  Some of the questions are completely out of date (assuming knowledge of pre-OSX Mac GUI) and many are frankly biased towards Tog's personal experiences.  Giving this quiz _verbatim_ is probably a good signal your company is behind the times.

Answer (score 8):

**Personal Experience** A good UX practitioner should be taking an interest in the things they use personally. I would ask them what they use personally - obvious technology items like phone and websites, and also less obvious things like kitchen appliances and vending machines. If a UX candidate can't tell me what they observed in their day so far (e.g. the car or public transport they used to get to the interview), that's a good way to weed out the dead weight right there.

**Practical Problems** As with programming, the best way to assess someone is give them a real-world problem you're facing (or faced) and see how they deal with it. Their thought processes are more important than the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I am a UI Designer/Developer and once I gave an interview to Verizon for UX Designer position. By the way, it was a phone interview. I never worked as UX Designer before. The person who interviewed me asked me about my past work experiences, skill sets and asked me if have contributed as UX designer before. With regards to technical question, he actually sent me a document which had some brief information (part of an application) and then a small interface (it was like a table with some graphic based information, and based on this information, the call center people would respond to user request). I was asked to study this table carefully and then i was given 24 hour timefame to suggest a changed table/design and was asked to explain why would i suggest those changes. Just by looking at that single page  document, I didn't understand the problem itself and didn't know what to suggest. I spent 23 hours just looking at the problem and on the 24th hour I did make a suggestion and send them my reply. But didn't work ..... i never heard back from Verizon.

As a UI Designer, I have worked wiith lots of UX Designer and all I know about UX design is that you have to understand the problem very carefully. You need to look for all posible solutions and use the one that would best satisfies the usesr needs. And then you must know how to create wireframes.

Answer (score 0):

Ask them how they would go about designing the UI for some system. Tell them to design a solution for some domain which you know well (for example one of your recent projects), so that in the interview you can take the role of the user. Then the UX consultant will need to dig the necessary requirements from you, find out what is the problem that needs to be solved, and then designing and testing a solution.

Or if you want to make it easier/quicker, use a domain that everybody knows, so that he doesn't need to dig the requirements from you. For example design a system for finding out in which of the nearby restaurants you would like to eat a dinner. In one hour you should get some understanding of what the consultant is like.

Answer (score 0):

Give them some screenshots* of example pages from a selection of sites, some of which you consider good, some bad, and in varying degrees. Ask them to point out good and bad features in each (and there is *some* good and bad in every site) and explain their thinking. If they fail to spot something obvious, prompt them with a neutral "what about X?" and see how they analyse it.

* finding these isn't hard, but a little time consuming possibly. Even better if you can give them access to an actual browser so you can go over the "live" elements

Answer (score 0):

UX work is made up of two parts: Research and Design. You need to be clear which you want most emphasis on: someone who can grok out massive taxonomies and build wireframes in their sleep, vs someone who has hundreds of hours of usability lab experience. (You can find people who have both areas of expertise, but people often lean in one direction).

Beware of UX consultants who have never been embedded in a scrum team before. They will need some bedding in time. If they are used to working agency-side rather than client-side, they will be used to doing shortish research projects and then leaving. [This kind of "skirmish"](http://www.90percentofeverything.com/2009/02/03/user-experience-research-skirmishes-are-you-guilty/) is quite different to the long-view you have to take when working client side.